# Combine values using Python conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create a new column containing all company description but I needed to clean the data.

Now, I'm doing

```
df['Combined-Description'] = df['Desc1'] + ' ' + df['Desc3'] + df['Desc1'] + ' ' + df['Desc4']
```

But this also includes entries I don't want, which are addresses, phone number and copyright statement.

How do I apply conditional statements to exclude

1. addresses (containing the word road),
2. phone number (containing + symbol or regex not required, I can research on my own)
3. URL (containing http)
4. Copyright (containing ©)

The end results would be Apple Inc, ignoring Desc1, Desc2 and Desc3 and only take Desc4

Whereas Amazon Inc, ignoring Desc2 and Desc4, taking only Desc1 and Desc3.

[image]

|  | Desc1 | Desc2 | Desc3 | Desc4 | Combined-Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple Inc | Service Street #03-03 | +1 (677) 256-700 | [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com) | Tech company | Tech company |
| Amazon Inc | E-commerce | Copyright © | Videos, movies |  | E-commerce Videos, movies |

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `filter(...)` function for this. It takes something that can be iterated over, and a function to filter with. In your case that could be something like

```py
NewDict = dict(filter(filterFunction, OldDict.items())
```

Where the filterfunction has the dict key-values as input and returns True or False. an example might be:

```py
def filterFunction(KeyValue):
    if KeyValue[1] == "road": #the value is the second element due to the .items call earlier
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This would create a filtered dictionary where all the values are the string `"road"` , of course the checking should be more complex for what you want, but i hope this makes the idea clear.

Some links about filters
https://thispointer.com/python-filter-a-dictionary-by-conditions-on-keys-or-values/
https://pythonguides.com/python-dictionary-filter/